# disable /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys for all users

Tags: ssh

each time i delete this file: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys , someone creates it again.

i deleted the file and checked if the user has ssh access or not, but i am sure he hasn't.

how can i disable the creation of these keys?

```
Is there a way that the user can create keys?
What about sftp? Does they use sftp to login?
```

i am using Centos 6 with Cpanel.

Comment: the problem is i find a lot of keys under: /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys

xxx = users on cpanel

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to prevent users from being able to log into a system via public key auth, you can set **PubkeyAuthentication** to 'no' in your sshd.conf (typically in /etc/ssh/sshd_config). Alternately you can set **AuthorizedKeysFile** to '/dev/null' to simply prevent sshd from looking at their file. This will probably be more effective than trying to prevent users from writing a file in their home directory.

Comment: Note that setting AuthorizedKeysFile to /dev/null works but will result in the following confusing warning: `User [username] authorized keys /dev/null is not a regular file`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the `authoized_keys` file by editing `sshd_config` and setting the new location with the `AuthorizedKeysFile` keyword. However,  It is inadvisable to completely disable public key authentication, which is what you would effectively do if you made it impossible to find an `authorized_key` file for any user, so you may consider some other options:

`AllowUsers` allows login only for specified users.

`AllowGroups` allows login only for the specified groups.

`DenyUsers` disallows login only for specified users.

`DenyGroups` disallows login only for specified groups.

More information on the `sshd_config` file is available by running `man sshd_config`.